# LINQ Join multiple conditions with OR operator

Tags: .net, linq

I have something like

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id], [t1].[DepartmentId]
FROM [ScannedDocuments] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Documents_RelatedDepartments] AS [t1]
    ON  (([t0].[Id] = [t1].[Id]) AND (1 = [t1].[DepartmentId]))
     OR (([t0].[Id] = [t1].[Id]) AND (56 = [t0].InsertById))
```

results as expected on sql server but I couldn't translate it to Linq. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that would be *something* like:

```
var query = from doc in context.ScannedDocuments
            join department in context.RelatedDocuments 
              on doc.Id equals department.Id
            where doc.InsertById == 56 || department.DepartmentId == 1
            select new { DocId = doc.Id, DepartmentId = department.Id };
```

Comment: Although other answers are working fine, this one is much like my style ;) Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from t0 in ctx.ScannedDocuments
from t1 in ctx.Documents_RelatedDepartments
where 
(
    (t0.Id == t1.Id) && (t1.Id == 1) ||
    (t0.Id == t1.Id) && (t0.InsertById == 56) 
)
select new {t0.Id, Id2=t1.Id, t1.DepartmentId}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler query.  Also note that the Id's are constrained to being the same by the join so you don't need both in the output.

```
db.ScannedDocuments
  .Where( s => s.InsertById == 56)
  .Join( db.Documents_RelatedDepartments
           .Where( d => d.DepartmentId == 1 ),
         o => o.Id,
         i => i.Id,
         (o,i) => new { o.Id, i => i.DepartmentId } )
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working standalone but when I try to merge it to my existing code (which has some more joins) I couldn't make it working.